# Importing .txt file in Matlab containing integers of 21 digits

Tags: matlab

I have a .txt file (named B.txt) composed of a list of integers (21 digits each) separated in two columns as follows (in practice the file contains many more rows):

```
116374117927631468606 101765416973555767821
112188647432305746617 107727150903234299458
116719211656774388392 100432456209427807893
117421021456205115327 101096322838605097368
```

I want to import this file in Matlab with a format that allows me to count how many times each integer is repeated in the second column.

What I am doing at the moment is

```
A=importdata('B.txt'); 
A_2=A(:,2);
a = unique(A_2);
out = [a,histc(A_2(:),a)];
```

Question: is there a better way to perform this task? For example, is there a way to "relabel" everything starting from 1?

In particular, I am wondering whether I lose precision by importing those huge integers as numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you loose precision. Try `112188647432305746617==112188647432305746616`.

I suggest you import the data as text, instead of numbers, and the use VPA. Using the same example:

```
a=vpa('112188647432305746617');
b=vpa('112188647432305746616');
a==b
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you be more precise on how I can rewrite my code using your suggestion? Also, is there a way to "relabel" everything starting from 1?

Comment: @user3285148 read the file with `fscanf`, put strings as `vpa`, and then put them in `A_2`. I do not understand what you mean by "relabel"

Comment: Thanks. When I use fscan which formatSpec should I enter?

Comment: @user3285148 The one that will achieve correct reading of your file. This should be easy to figure out.

Comment: OK, thanks, but it don't know how to make it working. I get A empty for any value of formatSpec I insert

Comment: @user3285148 `fscanf(id, '%s %s')`?

Comment: Still empty. Could it be due to lack of memory? But when I use importdata I don't have issues.

Comment: Are you forgetting to close the file and open again? @user3285148. It works for me.

Comment: It works now. However, it gives me a 1x1 char (basically it shrinks all the numbers together). How should I proceed then?

Comment: I have also tried `fileID = fopen('B.txt', 'r');

formatSpec = '%s %s';
sizeA = [4 2];

A=fscanf(fileID, formatSpec, sizeA); ` but it does not split everything in two columns

Comment: Maybe `textscan` does the job? Also, `vpa` does not seem to work with `hist`

Comment: No ofense, but all this side-problems you have you can fix in 5 minutes of thinking. You dont need `histc`you can use the other outputs from `unique`. Your problem was the big numbers and I tried to give you a solution to that. Best of lucks.